# Confidence interval for Poisson variables

Tags: statistics, self-learning, poisson-distribution

Let $X_{i},...,X_{n}$ be i.i.d. Poisson random variables with parameter $\lambda>0$

I have:

$$\bar{X}={(1/n)\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}.$$

Find two sequences $(a_n)_{n>=1}$ and $(b_n)_{n>=1}$ such that $a_n(\bar{X}-b_n)$ converges in distribution to a standard Gaussian random variable $Z$~$N(0,1)$

I'm trying to find the values for the sequence $(a_n)_{n>=1}$ and $(b_n)_{n>=1}$ such that:

$$c_n=a_n*({(1/n)\sum_{i=1}^n X_i} + b_n)$$ converges in distribution to a standard Gaussian random variable.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! Take the short [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how how to get the most from your time here. For typesetting equations please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your unusual equation for $\bar X.$ The title of the question mentions confidence intervals, but the question itself seems not to make a connection with CIs. Please clarify.

Comment: Yes, I just edited the question. I wasn't  clear enough. I´m trying to find the sequences such that $c_n$ converges in distribution to a standard Gaussian random variable.

Answer (score 1):

Without explicitly working your exact problem, I will illustrate a few methods of finding a 95% CI for
Poisson $\lambda.$

There is much literature on this general topic, with perhaps as many as a dozen reasonable types if CIs used in various applications. For large $\lambda$ (say above 30 or so) most of the methods give roughly the same numerical results. I suppose others may want to show additional types of Poisson CIs.

**Wald asymptotic interval.** In order to test $H_0: \lambda = \lambda_0$ against $H_a: \lambda \ne \lambda_0,$ based on $T$ Poisson events, one can
use the test statistic
$$Z = \frac{T - \lambda_0}{\sqrt{\lambda_0}} \stackrel{aprx}{\sim} \mathsf{Norm}(0,1).$$

Inverting this test in a naive way, one obtains the 95% CI $$T \pm 1.96\sqrt{T}.$$ The idea is that values of $\lambda_0$ that would not lead to rejection for a given $T$ at the 5% level of significance form a 95% CI for $\lambda.$

Two approximations involved here, both of which become reasonably good for large $T.$ One is that $\frac{T - \lambda_0}{\sqrt{\lambda_0}}$ is approximately standard normal; the other is that $\sqrt{\lambda_0}$ in the denominator is well-approximated by $T.$

**"Agresti-Style" CI.** If we solve the quadratic inequality for a somewhat more accurate inversion of the test, and conflate 1.96 with 2, we get the CI 
$$T +2 \pm 1.96\sqrt{T+1}.$$ This interval is somewhat in the spirit of the well-known "plus-Four" or "Agresti-Coull" Ci for the binomial success probability. [This type of interval uses only the asymptotic normality of a Poisson distribution with increaseing $\lambda.]$

**Bayesian flat-prior interval estimate used as a CI.** This interval uses the posterior distribution
$\mathsf{Gamma}(.5 + t, 1)$ and cuts 2.5% of the probability from each tail. [Philosophical interpretations of Bayesian posterior probability intervals and frequentist confidence intervals differ,
but many frequentists are willing to use numerical results of
Bayesian methods in frequentist estimation.]

**Examples:** Suppose $T = 30$ Poisson events are
observed in a domain (e.g., time period, area, or volume) and we want to estimate the Poisson rate $\lambda$ for that domain. [I choose $T = 20$ because it is small enough to give noticeably different results
for the three intervals; for $T=50,$ the three results are much alike.]

The three types of CIs are computed as
follows:

Wald: $30 \pm 1.96\sqrt{20}$ or $(11.24, 28.77).$

Agresti: $22 \pm 1.96\sqrt{21}$ or $(13.02, 30.98).$
A grid search for the exact inversion of the test
gives the interval $(12.95, 30.89).$

```
lam = seq(5, 50, by=.0001)
z = (20 - lam)/sqrt(lam)
ci = lam[z > -1.96 & z < 1.96]
min(ci); max(ci)
[1] 12.9475
[1] 30.8941
```

Bayesian: $(12.61, 30.29)$

```
qgamma(c(.025, .975), 20.5, 1)
[1] 12.60726 30.28029
```

If $n$ observations are taken from the domain
and their average is $T/n,$ simply divide the
interval endpoints by $n.$

**Actual coverage probability.** Because of the discrete nature of Poisson counts and the use of approximations, alleged "95%" confidence intervals do not have
exactly 95% coverage for all values of $\lambda.$
The "Agresti" style has very nearly the intended
coverage for $\lambda$ sufficiently large.
For this style of 95% confidence intervals, the graph below shows actual coverage for
2000 values of $\lambda \in [4,75].$

[image]

By contrast, the Wald-style CIs have less than
the intended coverage probability for many values of $\lambda.$

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't  clear enough. I´m trying to find the sequences such that $c_n$ converges in distribution to a standard Gaussian random variable.

Comment: Thanks for revising the equation about $\bar X.$ Now you need to think about the connection between the sequences and the 'confidence interval' in the title. Can you show what you have done toward finding the sequences?